# Custom time interval in bar chart has no gaps between bars

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I created my own `d3-time` [interval](https://github.com/d3/d3-time/blob/master/README.md#timeInterval) and added it to the switching time intervals [example](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/switching-time-intervals.html) (ported to this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lcxg6594/)).
But I'm unhappy with the result. The gaps between two bars are not shown. 
[image: screenshot of fiddle]

I'd like the bars looking with a gap as all the other intervals. I suspect my implementation of the custom interval is wrong, but I cannot figure out what the problem is. 
I used this implementation in another project and there the opposite happened: The gaps are maximal large and the bars very small.

```js
var threeMonthsInterval = d3.timeInterval(
    function (date) {
        date.setDate(1);
        date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
        var currentMounth = date.getMonth()
        if (currentMounth <= 2) {
            // 'Q1';
            date.setMonth(0)
        } else if (currentMounth > 2 && currentMounth <= 5) {
            // 'Q2';
            date.setMonth(3)
        } else if (currentMounth > 5 && currentMounth <= 8) {
            // 'Q3';
            date.setMonth(6)
        } else {
            // 'Q4';
            date.setMonth(9)
        }
    },    
    function (date, step) {
        date.setMonth(date.getMonth() * 3 + step);
    },
    function (start, end) {
        return (end.getMonth() - start.getMonth()) / 3 + (end.getFullYear() - start.getFullYear()) * 3;
    },    
    function (date) {
        return date.getMonth() * 3;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one that counts the number between two dates

```
function (start, end) {
    return (end.getMonth() - start.getMonth()) / 3 + (end.getFullYear() - start.getFullYear()) * 3;
},
```

is the one that tells dc.js how many bars to plan for, and therefore how wide they should be.

I haven't tested your code, so there could be other problems, but there are four quarters in a year, so that last number should be 4.

Comment: Thank you, that was it and another problem as well. I feel a bit embarrassed. Do you think the example could benefit from the additional timespan? If you think so, I’m happy to provide a PR. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Here is the link of the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/christianmurschall/upf4w07g/) and how the example would look like

Comment: Yeah that would be great, please do! Something I've wanted to try.